# Displaying Link Count of Each WordPress Category Inside The <a> Tag Itself

Tags: wordpress

As you probably know, to get the category list in WordPress, you use:

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&show_count=1&title_li='); ?>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to get it without `<li>`, and display link counts of each category inside the `<a>` tag itself?

For example, I want to use this structure for categories:

```
<nav>
    <a href="?cat=1">Arabesque (3)</a>
    <a href="?cat=2">Business (5)</a>
</nav>
```

instead of this typical one:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="?cat=1">Arabesque</a> (3)</li>
    <li><a href="?cat=2">Business</a> (5)</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: wp_list_cats Deprecate see this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_cats

Comment: Updated to the new function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use a filter:

```
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'mytheme_category_list' );
function mytheme_category_list( $list ) {
    //remove ul tags
    $list = str_replace( '<ul>', '', $list );
    $list = str_replace( '</ul>', '', $list );
    //remove li tags
    $list = preg_replace( '~<li(.*?)>~s', '', $list );
    $list = str_replace( '</li>', '', $list );
    //move count inside a tags
    $list = str_replace( '</a> (', '(', $list );
    $list = str_replace( ')', ')</a>', $list );
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works also with `wp_list_pages`, but not with `wp_get_archives`; isn't supposed to work with this function too?

Comment: for the archives use the filter get_archives_link instead of wp_get_archives

Answer (score 0):

To move the post count inside the `a` tag, use this snippet in your functions.php file:

```
function prefix_move_category_count( $links ) {
    $links = str_replace( '</a> <span class="count">', ' <span class="count">', $links );
    $links = str_replace( '</span>', '</span></a>', $links );
    return $links;
}
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'prefix_move_category_count' );
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/blainerobison/1f1e59c99f5c9a78b93d

Comment: Should be added to `functions.php`, right? It didn't work.

Comment: Switch on debugging in `wp-config.php`, do you see any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Got it from GitHub https://gist.github.com/blainerobison/1f1e59c99f5c9a78b93d

Works Perfectly

/**
 * Move Category Post Counts Inside Link
 *
 * filters wp_list_categories()
 * 
 * @param  string $links link html output
 * @return string
 */
function prefix_move_category_count( $links ) {

```
$links = str_replace( '</a> <span class="count">', ' <span class="count">', $links );
$links = str_replace( '</span>', '</span></a>', $links );

return $links;
```

}
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'prefix_move_category_count' );

/**
 * Move Archive Post Counts Inside Link
 *
 * filters get_archives_link()
 * 
 * @param  string $links link html output
 * @return string
 */
function prefix_move_archive_count($links) {

```
$links = str_replace( '</a>&nbsp;(', ' <span class="count">(', $links );
$links = str_replace( ')', ')</span></a>', $links );

return $links;
```

}
add_filter( 'get_archives_link', 'prefix_move_archive_count' );